# Немного не так работает karma npm

Tags: node.js

Установил в webstorm пакет karma. Делал по [гайду](http://youtube.com/watch?v=QQSySPpzmPI).

Но возникла следующая проблема.

```
/**
* Created by Maks on 15.01.2016.
*/
var HelloWorld = function(World) {
console.log("Hello, World" + " " + World + "!");
}

HelloWorld("");
HelloWorld("abcd");
```

Это основной код, который содержится в подпапке проекта под названием js/

Вот часть конфига, которую исправлял в karma.conf.js:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: ['js/*.js','tests/*.js'
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: ['js/dontTestIt.js'
],
```

Вот сам тест validate_test.js из tests:

```
/**
* Created by Maks on 15.01.2016.
*/
describe("The name validator", function(){
    describe("Checks for empty string", function(){
        it("should return true when the string is empty",function(){
            expect(HelloWorld("")).toBe(true);
        });
        it("should return false when the string is not empty",function(){
            expect(HelloWorld("abcd")).toBe(false);
        });
    });
});
```

Само тестрирование запускается, но вот ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, текст ошибки текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: 'Hello, World !'
'Hello, World abcd!'
'Hello, World !'

 Expected undefined to be true.
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Users/Maks/WebstormProjects/untitled1/tests/validate_test.js:7:36)

Comment: 'Hello, World !'
'Hello, World abcd!'
'Hello, World !'

 Expected undefined to be true.
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Users/Maks/WebstormProjects/untitled1/tests/validate_test.js:7:36)

'Hello, World abcd!'

 Expected undefined to be false.
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Users/Maks/WebstormProjects/untitled1/tests/validate_test.js:10:40)

Comment: Проблема собствено в том, что функция `HelloWorld` при вызове ничего явно не возвращает, а неявно по умолчанию возвращает `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

По сути не правильно написан тест.
HelloWorld ничего не возвращает, потому как бы неявно возвращается **undefined**, как заметили в комментариях.
В качестве решения два пути:

1. переписать тест с учётом вышеприведенной особенности
2. переписать код так чтобы он смог информировать о состоянии выполнения функций

Причём второй вариант, как по мне, предпочтительнее.